# How can I save appended html to the document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say I append html via jquery to an element. How can I make it so that it's saved so each time you load the page, the newly appended html to the element will still apply?

Comment: If you are expecting this to be a feature of the browser or web in general, then the answer is that you can't. It would be possible to hack it yourself by using local storage, but I doubt that's the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Use `localStorage` to save the value of the elements (or content inside tags) locally, and restore on fresh page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are asking here is maintaining state in case of page reload
you can do this multiple ways
1. Use Localstorage to save the appended html and then inside $(function(){}) retrieve the html and append it again.
2.everytime you append the HTML change the hash of the document programmatically so then whenever you go that page again you can read the hash and send a fresh AJAX request to retrieve the html content and then append it

Answer (score 0):

Quick way of doing it via localStorage (which means you will need a [modern browser](http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage))

**Save HTML**

```
window.onunload = function() { 
    localStorage.setItem(
        "page_"+window.location.pathname,
        document.body.innerHTML
    ); 
};
```

**Load HTML**

```
window.onload = function() { 
    document.body.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("page_"+window.location.pathname);
};
```

This does not guarantee 100% consistency, one example is that if you have `iframes` pointing to external domains then their `src` attribute will not be copied.

Comment: Really appreciate it. I wonder if what I intend to use this solution for is superfluous. I have a simple to do list app. When you add a task to do, the text is appended to an li element and the li element is styled to display a rectangle with the text inside of it and a progress bar. Say I have several tasks added, when I click one of the rectangle's it will use toggleClass to add a class which will style it to look selected. So it'll add .Selected to the li element I clicked. I will then be taken to a page that has a "Done" button. When I press that, it'll present a page with a slider.

Comment: With the slider, I will choose between 1-10 to determine how much of the task I've completed. 10 being the highest. If I select 10, I was thinking it would target the specific task using the .Selected class and make the progress bar display 100%. Then I would want this saved with your solution. Is there an easier way?

Comment: @user974725 saving the resultant HTML markup is not the right way of doing this. You should instead save only the value of the slider and any other info such as the selected element. Then use that information to properly render what is displayed on the page the next time it loads.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of a website it is, but if the changes made to the DOM are meant to be permanent, and changes are only permitted to be made by registered users, I would maybe write the HTML snippet to a file, and keep track of the changes in the database. And then render the HTML snippet every time the page is requested.